# Optional named arguments in Mathematica

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, named-parameters

What's the best/canonical way to define a function with optional named arguments?  To make it concrete, let's create a function `foo` with named arguments `a`, `b`, and `c`, which default to 1, 2, and 3, respectively.  For comparison, here's a version of `foo` with positional arguments:

```
foo[a_:1, b_:2, c_:3] := bar[a,b,c]
```

Here is sample input and output for the named-arguments version of `foo`:

```
foo[]                  --> bar[1,2,3]
foo[b->7]              --> bar[1,7,3]
foo[a->6, b->7, c->8]  --> bar[6,7,8]
```

It should of course also be easy to have positional arguments before the named arguments.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682742/optional-named-arguments-without-wrapping-them-all-in-optionvalue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the standard way to do it in the Mathematica documentation:  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html

```
Options[foo] = {a->1, b->2, c->3};  (* defaults *)
foo[OptionsPattern[]] := bar[OptionValue@a, OptionValue@b, OptionValue@c]
```

Typing "OptionValue" every time is a little cumbersome. For some reason you can't just make a global abbreviation like `ov = OptionValue` but you can do this:

```
foo[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{ov},
  ov[x___] := OptionValue[x];
  bar[ov@a, ov@b, ov@c]]
```

Or this:

```
With[{ov = OptionValue},
  foo[OptionsPattern[]] := bar[ov@a, ov@b, ov@c]
]
```

Or this:

```
$PreRead = ReplaceAll[#, "ov" -> "OptionValue"] &;

foo[OptionsPattern[]] := bar[ov@a, ov@b, ov@c]
```

Comment: About cumbersome typing of OptionValue : In this case you could say `In[32]:= OptionValue /@ bar[a, b, c]

Out[32]= bar[OptionValue[a], OptionValue[b], OptionValue[c]]`

Comment: @dreeves There is a more concise form of the last code block using `With` rather than `Module`.  May I edit your answer to append this?

Comment: @Sjoerd funny, your comment was not there when I loaded this page.  I guess you're reading these old posts too.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yep, triggered by dreeves' chain of questions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Please do! (I don't think you need to ask in general; reverting is easy if the original author doesn't like the edit.) Oh, and don't append, just change it if it's better.

Comment: @dreeves I know the site allows that, but it still seems polite to ask.  BTW, I don't know if it's better, just a different style.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Are you sure that PreRead trick is safe? What if "ov" is just part of another string or redefined in a Block or something? Also, did you test the With version? There's something weird about OptionValue; confer my "For some reason you can't...".

Comment: I did test these, but recall that I am using Mma 7.  The `With` version works because replacement is done before evaluation.  The `$PreRead` version appears safe because it operates at the token level.  Try evaluating: `{7 "ov", 2 + ov, "stove", rover}`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `OptionValue` can be a bit tricky because is relies on a piece of magic so that

> `OptionValue[name]` is equivalent to `OptionValue[f,name]`, where `f` is the head of the left-hand side of the transformation rule in which `OptionValue[name]` appears.

Throwing in an explicit `Automatic` usually does the trick, so in your case I would say that the solution is:

```
Options[foo] = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3};
foo[OptionsPattern[]] := 
  bar @@ (OptionValue[Automatic, #] &) /@ First /@ Options[foo]
```

By the way, options used to be done by matching to `opts:___?OptionQ`, and then finding option values manually as `{a,b,c}/.Flatten[{opts}]`. The pattern check `OptionQ` is still around (although not documented), but the `OptionValue` approach has the advantage that you get warnings for non-existing options (e.g. `foo[d->3]`). This would also be the case for your second response, but not for the one you have accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw this possible solution into the mix:

```
foo[opts___Rule] := Module[{f},
  f@a = 1; (* defaults... *)
  f@b = 2;
  f@c = 3;
  each[a_->v_, {opts}, f@a = v];

  Return[bar[f@a, f@b, f@c]]
]
```

I like it for its terseness but I don't think it's the standard way.  Any gotchas with doing it that way?

PS, it uses the following handy utility function:

```
SetAttributes[each, HoldAll];                (* each[pattern, list, body]     *)
each[pat_, lst_, bod_] :=                    (*  converts pattern to body for *)
  Scan[Replace[#, pat:>bod]&, Evaluate@lst]  (*   each element of list.       *)
```